# Get form to be responzive while being in the center of the screen at att screnn sizes

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my forms to stay in the middle of the screen and scale according to the size of the middle section of my site. Right now for most sizes it's ok but when the screen gets small the form overlaps with my navbar section and my footer section because the size of my form doesn't change. Here's an example of one of my forms with the navbar,body and footer styling. For the most part they're all similar in terms of styling.
HTML

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.topnav{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh / 10);
    background-color: #2B78E4;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
}
.topnav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #fff1f1;
    color: Black;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-style: inherit;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.nav-btn{
    background-color: #fff1f1;
    color: Black;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
#login-btn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#signUp-btn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#login-btn, #signUp-btn {
    float: right;
}
#nav-teams{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    background-color: #666666;
}
footer {
    background-color: #999999;
    background-size: 50px;
    height : calc(100vh/8);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer-links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.footer-links a {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#signup-title-init{
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
#signup-title-init h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

#signup-body-init h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#signup-body-init p {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

#signup-footer-init p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
#signup-footer-init{
    border-top:1px solid ;
}
.entry{
    width:100%;
}
#signup-footer-init a {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-signup-init {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 45%;
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    visibility: visible;

}
.terms-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.resend-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#terms-link{
    color:blue;
}
#terms{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#termsError{
    display:none;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<header>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href = homepage.html>
            <img src="images/fb-helmet.png" alt="Logo" class = "helmet-logo">
        </a>
        <div class="teams-btn" id="nav-teams">
            <button class="nav-btn" ><a href="Teams.html">Teams</a></button>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Seasons
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Seasons.html">2022</a>
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2021">2021</a>
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2020">2020</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="login-btn">
            <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href="SignIn.html">Log In</a></button>
        </div>

        <div id="signUp-btn">
            <button class="nav-btn" ><a href ="Signup.html">Sign Up</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<body>
<form id="signUp-init">
    <div class="popup-signup-init">
        <div id="signup-title-init">
            <h2>Sign Up for CollegeFB-Archive</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="signup-body-init">
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
            <input class="entry" type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label><br>
            <input class="entry" type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required>
            <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
            <input class="entry" type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <label for="password">Confirm Password:</label><br>
            <input class="entry" type="password" id="confirm-password" name="password" required>
            <div class="terms-container">
                <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms">
                <label for="terms">I agree to the </label><a id="terms-link" href="Terms%20of%20Use.html">Terms of Service</a>
            </div><br>
            <p id="termsError" >You must accept the terms of service.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Continue">
        </div>
        <div id="signup-footer-init">
            <div class="resend-container">
                <p>Did not get the email?</p><a href="#">Click here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
<footer>
    <div class="footer-logo">
        <a href = homepage.html>
            <img src="images/fb-helmet.png" alt="Logo" class="helmet-logo">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-links">
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="Terms%20of%20Use.html">Terms of Use</a>
    </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

so far I've attempted playing with the position setting but anything other than absolute moves the form up and overlapping with the navbar and outside of the view screen. I've attempted adjusting the height and width of the div the form is in and that affects the form container but not the inputs and labels within that form.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this via media queries, like

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .popup-signup-init {
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

Tested the above and it was almost perfect, you will need to figure out the exact bounds for this specific media query, but the idea should be the path you need to go through in order to solve this problem.

```css
.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 0 20px;
    background-color: white;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.topnav{
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vh / 10);
    background-color: #2B78E4;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
}
.topnav a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
}
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #fff1f1;
    color: Black;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 16px;
    font-style: inherit;
}
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
}
.nav-btn{
    background-color: #fff1f1;
    color: Black;
    padding: 8px 16px;
}
#login-btn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: auto;
}
#signUp-btn{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    float: right;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
#login-btn, #signUp-btn {
    float: right;
}
#nav-teams{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica", sans-serif;
    background-color: #666666;
}
footer {
    background-color: #999999;
    background-size: 50px;
    height : calc(100vh/8);
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-top: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.footer-links {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
.footer-links a {
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#signup-title-init{
     margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
#signup-title-init h2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

#signup-body-init h1 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
}

#signup-body-init p {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: center;
}

#signup-footer-init p {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
#signup-footer-init{
    border-top:1px solid ;
}
.entry{
    width:100%;
}
#signup-footer-init a {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.popup-signup-init {
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 45%;
    max-width: 400px;
    background-color: #999;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    visibility: visible;

}
.terms-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

.resend-container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
#terms-link{
    color:blue;
}
#terms{
    margin-right: 5px;
}
#termsError{
    display:none;
    color:red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .popup-signup-init {
        width: 20%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Sign Up</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<header>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href = homepage.html>
            <img src="images/fb-helmet.png" alt="Logo" class = "helmet-logo">
        </a>
        <div class="teams-btn" id="nav-teams">
            <button class="nav-btn" ><a href="Teams.html">Teams</a></button>
        </div>

        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn">Seasons
                <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="Seasons.html">2022</a>
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2021">2021</a>
                <a href="www.collegefbarchive.com/seasons/2020">2020</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="login-btn">
            <button class = "nav-btn" ><a href="SignIn.html">Log In</a></button>
        </div>

        <div id="signUp-btn">
            <button class="nav-btn" ><a href ="Signup.html">Sign Up</a></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<body>
<form id="signUp-init">
    <div class="popup-signup-init">
        <div id="signup-title-init">
            <h2>Sign Up for CollegeFB-Archive</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="signup-body-init">
            <label for="email">Email:</label><br>
            <input class="entry" type="email" id="email" name="email" required>
            <label for="fullname">Full Name:</label><br>
            <input class="entry" type="text" id="fullname" name="fullname" required>
            <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
            <input class="entry" type="password" id="password" name="password" required>
            <label for="password">Confirm Password:</label><br>
            <input class="entry" type="password" id="confirm-password" name="password" required>
            <div class="terms-container">
                <input type="checkbox" id="terms" name="terms">
                <label for="terms">I agree to the </label><a id="terms-link" href="Terms%20of%20Use.html">Terms of Service</a>
            </div><br>
            <p id="termsError" >You must accept the terms of service.</p>
            <input type="submit" value="Continue">
        </div>
        <div id="signup-footer-init">
            <div class="resend-container">
                <p>Did not get the email?</p><a href="#">Click here</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
<footer>
    <div class="footer-logo">
        <a href = homepage.html>
            <img src="images/fb-helmet.png" alt="Logo" class="helmet-logo">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-links">
        <a href="Contact.html">Contact Us</a>
        <a href="Terms%20of%20Use.html">Terms of Use</a>
    </div>
</footer>
</html>
```